# Cannot get Facebook Sample to run, says missing 'gen' folder

Tags: android

I followed the directions from 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/
to install the face book sdk and sample projects.

The projects all show up in my package explower, but they all have a red dor next to them.
When i click on the problems tab at the begging i get

Project facebookSDK is missing required source folder 'gen'
oject FriendsPickerSample is missing required source folder 'gen'
oject GraphApiSample is missing required source folder 'gen'
....
....
.....

Answer (score 0):

You should set a project SDK that you have installed on your computer. You can check this in your project properties, Android page. Check the project build target there.

Comment: Hi, could you explain more.  I did inport the sdk from facebook and all its sample projects show up. but they all have errors that say "missing requred source folder gen" and idears??????

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you have defined the Facebook SDK project as a library project (Properties..Android..Is Library ticked)

Then this library project should be referenced in the sample project(s). (Properties ..Android..Reference..Add)

Then clean your projects and the errors should disappear.

That's one way of doing it anyway ... Hope this helps ...

Comment: Thank you for your help those I checked the facebook sdk was defined as a lib and theb properties wehre set.  I clean my project and still get "missing requre source folder gen"